Extension of a vector bundle over the smooth compactification of an algebraic variety
This questions arises while reading an article by Cornalba and Griffiths. The following is the link to the paper (actually the whole volume of the journal).
https://eudml.org/doc/142315
On page 23, they defined an algebraic vector bundle $E \rightarrow A$ as a Zariski open covering with rational holomorphic transition maps. They said that in this case, we have a smooth compactification $\overline{A}$ of $A$ and algebraic vector bundle $\overline{E} \rightarrow \overline{A}$ such that this extends the original bundle $E \rightarrow A$. I think this can be proved using some facts from algebraic geometry, but I am not sure how to do that. Note that they just say that $A$ is an algebraic variety, but I guess that means a quasi-projective variety.
In fact, what I need is actually the simplest case: $A = \mathbb{C} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Let me assume $A$ is quasi-projective. Let $D$ be an ample divisor on $A$. Then for $n \gg 0$ the twist $E(nD)$ is generated by a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ of global sections, i.e., there is an epimorphism
$$
V \otimes \mathcal{O}_A \to E(nD).
$$
This epimorphism defines a morphism to the Grassmannian $f \colon A \to \mathrm{Gr}(r,V^\vee)$ such that $E(nD)$ is isomorphic to the pullback of the dual tautological bundle.
Now let $A'$ be any compactification of $A$. Let
$$
A'' \subset A' \times \mathrm{Gr}(r,V^\vee)
$$
be the closure of the graph of $f$. Then $A''$ is a compactification (not smooth in general) of $A$ and the pullback of the the dual tautological bundle provides an extension $E''$ of $E(nD)$ to $A''$. Finally, let $\bar{A}$ be a resolution of singularities of $A''$ and let $E'''$ be the pullback of $E''$ to $\bar{A}$. This provides an extension of $E(nD)$ to a smooth compactification.
It remains to consider the closure $\bar{D} \subset \bar{A}$ of the divisor $D$ in $\bar{A}$ and define $\bar{E} := E'''(-n\bar{D})$.
